# How to access application deployed in minikube remotely

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am using `kubernetes` to deploy my application on `minikube`. After deploying using command

```
minikube service helloworld-all-service --url
```

Which shows some `URL` to access the application. Something like

```
http://192.168.49.2:32474
```

I was to access this application from a different machine on the same network. I tried `port-forwarding`

```
kubectl port-forward service/helloworld-all-service 8080:8080
```

This allowed me access application using `localhost:8080/myApp`. But when I tried using my system IP it didn't work `10.14.77.88:8080/myApp`. What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the port is only bound to localhost, to make it also available on the external address you need to specify the bind address (0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces on the machine):

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/helloworld-all-service 8080:8080
```

Comment: I set up a Minikube cluster of two nodes in my home lab with an NGINX reverse proxy running as a Podman container on the same host so I can reach the Control Plane from remote hosts with `kubectl`; so far, so good. The problem I'm facing now is that I can't reach any of the ingresses of the applications deployed in the cluster. I'm employing your workaround to expose the services directly on different ports. While this is a less-than-stellar solution, it is a convenient way to quickly host multiple applications in the cluster, at least until I learn how to do it correctly. Thanks for sharing!